# How can I transfer a parameter in an UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, dependency-properties

I have a complex page with an independant UserControl (has its own ViewModel), and I want to transfer one parameter. I'm thinking of two solution :

- DependencyProperty for UserControl
- MVVM Light messenger (By the way, how to make unique the message between sender and recorder? With NotificationMessage?)

Please, could you help me to find the most appropriate solution for MVVM architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i declared the UserControl ViewModel in View ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a CLR property on the ViewModel, unless you have other requirements that you don't mention.

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for your response, my page have a ViewModel and my UserControl have another